# How to get id of pause button along with play button id when play button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the id of the pause button along with the play button id when the play button is clicked? As I want multiple play button. so I need a function that could serve all buttons. Here I have to first fetch play button id then pause button id. Also i have to write id of pause button like `document.getElementById('pausebutton');` I want to fetch its Id in function too. I am not able to get both button ids in one function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<i class="fa fa-play" style="font-size:24px;" id="playbutton" onclick="togglePlay('play',document.getElementById('myAudio'),this.id)"></i>
<i class="fa fa-pause" style="font-size:24px;display:none;" id="pausebutton" onclick="togglePause('pause',document.getElementById('myAudio'),this.id)"></i>

<a href="http://localhost/bkportfolio/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ENG_US_M_DaveL.mp3" download="ENG_US_M_DaveL.mp3"><button>Download</button></a>

<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="http://localhost/bkportfolio/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ENG_US_M_DaveL.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
function togglePlay(state,aid,playid) {
var p=playid;

    var audio = aid,
        play  = document.getElementById(p),
        pause = document.getElementById('pausebutton');

    if (state == 'play') {
        audio.play();
        play.style.display = 'none';
        pause.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
function togglePause(state,aid,pauseid) {
var p=pauseid;

    var audio = aid,
        pause  = document.getElementById(p),
        play = document.getElementById('playbutton');

    if (state == 'pause') {
        audio.pause();
        play.style.display = 'block';
        pause.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `document.querySelectorAll` to find a reference to the buttons and assign an event handler to them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the `pause.id` in the `togglePlay` function when you're getting the `play.id`.
`let pauseId = play.nextSibling.id`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code.
Steps > Get all button with same class or id > loop over them and add event listener > Write your logic inside them

```
<div>
  <button class="button">Play</button>
  <button class="button">Pause</button>
</div>


let  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');


for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('hello' + i)
    //write your logic here
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that `"... multiple play button."` indicates multiple audio elements perhaps the following approach might be of interest. With the original approach there would be problems using ID attributes to identify elements when there are multiple on the page.

It is admittedly more complicated Javascript wise but does have greater flexibility so I hope it'll be useful.

```js
let oColAudio=[];

const getfile=function(path){
  return path.split('/').pop()
};
const setname=function(e){
  e.target.parentNode.querySelector('span').dataset.track='Now playing: '+getfile( e.target.parentNode.dataset.src )
};
const unsetname=function(e){
  e.target.parentNode.querySelector('span').dataset.track='';
};
const togglestate=function(e){
  /* 
    get references to the play/pause elements 
    and toggle their display property.
  */
  let play=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('[data-task="play"]');
  let pause=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('[data-task="pause"]');

  play.style.display = play.style.display=='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  pause.style.display = pause.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
};
const pausetracks=function(e,node){
  /*
    iterate through all audio elements
    if it is playing, pause it and switch
    button display properties
  */
  oColAudio.forEach( audio=>{
    audio.pause();
    if( node!=audio ){
      audio.parentNode.querySelector('.fa-play').style.display='block';
      audio.parentNode.querySelector('.fa-pause').style.display='none';
      audio.parentNode.querySelector('span').dataset.track='';
    }
  })
};

/* 
  obtain list of ALL play/pause elements and assign listeners to each 
  after setting the src attribute for the audio element and setting the
  properties for the download link.
*/
document.querySelectorAll('i.fa-play,i.fa-pause').forEach( node=>{
  let src=node.parentNode.dataset.src;

  let audio=node.parentNode.querySelector('audio.myAudio');
    audio.querySelector('source').src=src;

  let bttn=node.parentNode.querySelector('a > button');
    bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      bttn.parentNode.download=getfile( bttn.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.src )
    });



  node.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // find the audio element & toggle play/pause
    audio=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('audio.myAudio');

    // pause any tracks that are currently playing
    pausetracks(e,audio);

    /*
      play or pause the audio track depending upon the current state of the "button" task
      The play method naturally returns a Promise so we can use that Promise to control program flow
      The pause method does not natively return a Promise so to achieve similar functionality to the play
      method manually create our own Promise chain.
    */
    switch( e.target.dataset.task ){
      case 'play':
        audio.load( audio.querySelector('source').src );
        audio.play()
          .then( ()=>setname( e ) )
          .catch( err=>console.log( err ) );
      break;
      case 'pause':
        new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
          if( audio.pause() )resolve( true )
        })
          .then( ()=>unsetname( e ) )
          .catch( err=>console.log( err ) )

      break;
    }

    // toggle the state of the button
    togglestate( e );
  });
});

// add all "audio" elements to the global array "tracks" so we can pause them all easily
document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach( node => oColAudio.push( node ) )
```

```css
.fa-play,
.fa-pause{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  border:2px dotted black;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  background:lightgray;
  margin:1rem;
  padding:1rem;
}

.fa-play{color:green}
.fa-pause{color:orange}

.fa-play + span,
.fa-pause + span{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 1rem;
  margin:0 1rem;
  width:200px;
  height:2rem;
  float:right;
  clear:none;
}

.fa-play + span:after,
.fa-pause + span:after{
  display:inline-block;
  content:attr(data-track)!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>


<div data-src='https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'><!-- Set the path for audio -->
  <i data-task='play' class='fa fa-play' style='font-size:24px;'></i>
  <i data-task='pause' class='fa fa-pause' style='font-size:24px;display:none;'></i>
  <span><!-- display track name --></span>

  <a href='#'>
    <button>Download</button>
  </a>
  <audio class='myAudio'>
    <source type='audio/mpeg'>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>


<div data-src='https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3'><!-- Set the path for audio -->
  <i data-task='play' class='fa fa-play' style='font-size:24px;'></i>
  <i data-task='pause' class='fa fa-pause' style='font-size:24px;display:none;'></i>
  <span><!-- display track name --></span>
  <a href='#'>
    <button>Download</button>
  </a>
  <audio class='myAudio'>
    <source type='audio/mpeg'>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>


<div data-src='https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/mp3/sample1.mp3'><!-- Set the path for audio -->
  <i data-task='play' class='fa fa-play' style='font-size:24px;'></i>
  <i data-task='pause' class='fa fa-pause' style='font-size:24px;display:none;'></i>
  <span><!-- display track name --></span>
  <a href='#'>
    <button>Download</button>
  </a>
  <audio class='myAudio'>
    <source type='audio/mpeg'>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```